# How do you declare or define generic xsd types within an existing type.

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have a Java spring based web service that returns a number of responses. I would like to design the response so that it is generic in that a number of fields are always available and that the result of calling the service is placed in a "payload" element in the JAXB responses. To do this, i came up with the following response type definition:

```
<xs:element name="serviceResponse">
    <xs:element name="responseStatus" type="xs:int"/>               
    <xs:element name="errorNumber" type="xs:int"/>
    <xs:element name="errorDescription" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="payLoad" type="?????"/>
</xs:element>
```

How can i declare the payLoad element if the type of that element can be different depending on the service type. Each service will generate a different JAXB type which i would like to add to the "PayloadElement". For example, here are a couple of example responses that i would expect:

List of customers:

```
<serviceResponse>
    <responseStatus>0</responsesStatus>
    <errorNumber>0</errorNumber>
    <errorDescription>null</errorDescription>
    <payLoad>
        <customers>
            <customer>
                <customerId>2323</customer>
                <customerName>Joe Bloggs</customerName>
                <invoiceNumber>90347347</invoiceNumber>
            </customer>
            <customer>
                <customerId>54</customer>
                <customerName>Dave hewitt</customerName>
                <invoiceNumber>342343</invoiceNumber>
            </customer>
        </customers>
    </payLoad>
</serviceResponse>
```

List of Orders

```
<serviceResponse>
    <responseStatus>0</responsesStatus>
    <errorNumber>0</errorNumber>
    <errorDescription>null</errorDescription>
    <payLoad>
        <orders>
            <order>

                <orderId>567</orderId>
                <ProductList>
                    <product>
                        <productId>234324</product>
                        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
                    </product>
                    <product>
                        <productId>23434</product>
                        <Quantity>7</Quantity>
                    </product>
                </ProductList>
            </order>
            <order>

                <orderId>34232</orderId>
                <ProductList>
                    <product>
                        <productId>1231</product>
                        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
                    </product>                  
                </ProductList>
            </order>
        </orders>
    </payLoad>
</serviceResponse>
```

As you can see the payload element can include an xml document that can be one of many types. How can i declare this in the serviceResponse element definition?

Thanks

Comment: The following should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

Answer (score 2):

Why not declare all possible types in the payload? something like:

```
<xs:element name="payloadContent">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element ref="customers" minOccurs="0"/>
       <xs:element ref="orders" minOccurs="0"/>
       <!-- more elements -->
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="payload" ref="payloadContent"/>
```